# working with methods to take in strings in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

I'm new to C and am having a lot of issues with arrays that keeps coming up. I'm trying to write a method that takes in a string ("1234") and returns the odd digits, however it keeps printing 49 and I don't know why? Does it have something to do with how I'm assigning the arrays?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int print_odd_digits(char number[100]) {
  int size = sizeof(number[100]);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (number[i] % 2 == 1) {
      printf("%d\n", number[i]);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  print_odd_digits("1234");
}
```

Comment: 49 is the ASCII code for `1` digit, try `printf("%d\n", number[i] - '0');`

Comment: `number[100]` is a single element of the `number` "array" (`number` is really a *pointer*). That means `sizeof(number[100])` is the size of one element. And since `number[100]` is a `char` it's the same as `sizeof(char)` which is defined to always be `1`.

Comment: To get the length of a string use `strlen` (which even pretty bad books or tutorials should have mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

- `sizeof(number[100])` is equivalent to `sizeof(char)`, which is `1`. What you want seems `strlen(number)`.
- Elements of `number` are not values of digits but character codes of digits. To convert number characters to values, you can subtract `'0'`. (character codes for `0` to `9` are defined to be continuous in C).
- `%d` is for printing integer and `49` is ASCII code for the character `1`. Use `%c` to print character corresponding to passed integer.
- You may want newline only on end of the characters.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* for using strlen() */
int print_odd_digits(char number[100]) {
    int size = strlen(number);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if((number[i] - '0') % 2 == 1){
            printf("%c",number[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int main(void) {
    print_odd_digits("1234");
}
```

Comment: The subscript operator used at the parameter is a common source of confusion and I personally consider it as bug. `number` is not an array of 100 `char`s nor a pointer to an array of 100 `char`s. I highly recommend to replace `char number [100]` by just `const char * number` or `const char const * number`. Just for the sake of clarity.

Comment: The 100 is also misleading because the array passed (and converted) in the function call from `main` is only 5 elements long!

Answer (score 0):

You have a type error here. You are working with the ascii codes for the text characters for digits. You need to use the atoi(char* str)
function to convert the digits to a corresponding number and use math to determine a particular digit or loop over the characters and subtract -'0' the ascii code for the digit zero as digits are sequential.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
        char* digit_one_str = "1";
        char digit_9 = '9';
        printf("digit one ascii value: %d\n", digit_one_str[0]); // first char in string digit one
        int number_one = atoi(digit_one_str);
        printf("digit one parsed from sttring by atoi: %d\n", number_one);
        printf("digit 9 as char converted with -'0' trick: %d", (int)(digit_9 - '0'));
}
```

Further it is better practice to take in a char* and a length than to work with fixed sized arrays or using strlen() where you don't actually have to. In C a string ends in a terminating '\0' character which might not even be present if the code calling your function is buggy or malicious.